# Prove an inequality involving frame operator $S$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$.

A sequence $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of elements in $\mathcal{H}$ is a frame for $\mathcal{H}$ if there exist constants $A, B>0$ such that
$$
A\|f\|^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 \leq B\|f\|^2, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{H} .
$$
Let $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a frame with frame operator $S$ and frame bounds $A, B$. Then it is easily to prove that $S$ is bounded, invertible, self-adjoint, and positive.

We can also prove that
$$A\|f\|^2 \leq\left\langle S f, f\right\rangle\leq B\|f\|^2, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{H} .$$
Let now $u=Sf\in\mathcal H$.
Is it possible to infer, from the previous inequality, that
$$\frac{\|u\|^2}{B} \leq\left\langle u, S^{-1} u\right\rangle \leq \frac{\|u\|^2}{A}$$
for each $u \in \mathcal{H}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T=S^{1/2}.$ The inequalities are equivalent to $$A\|v\|^2\le \|Tv\|^2\le B\|v\|^2$$ Let $v=T^{-1}u.$ Then $$A\|T^{-1}u\|^2\le \|u\|^2\le B\|T^{-1}u\|^2$$ Equivalently
$$ B^{-1}\|u\|^2\le \|T^{-1/2}u\|^2\le A^{-1}\|u\|^2$$ The conclusion follows as $\langle u, S^{-1}u\rangle =\|T^{-1/2}u\|^2.$

Comment: Hi Ryszard Szwarc, thank you for your answer. I accepted it two weeks ago, and at that time, no comments occurred to me. I suspect your proof is valid only in the finite-dimensional case, correct me if I'm wrong. Moreover, you defined $T=S^{1/2}$: why can you define $T$ in this way? Moreover, you wrote $T^{-1}$: from what can I deduce that $T$ is invertible?